# Repeat statement for switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, break, dev-c++, c++builder-6

So I want make the program that can input data many times, for example I choose case 1 again after I use case 1 to input data. Or I choose case 2 many times to see all data as I want.

Mostly said break statement bring the solution. But, when I using break statement after case, the program was terminated. So how I can make repeat switch statement without make terminating program?

If I make this, the switch case happen sequentially. Example, I can input case 1 normally but when I input case 1 again it will go to next case instead case 1 and vice versa until exit case. This is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma hdrstop

using namespace std;

struct ig
{
int id;
string name;
ig *next;
ig *prev;
};
ig *head= NULL;
ig *tail= NULL;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

cout<<"+---------------------------------------+"<<endl;
cout<<"|    Instagram User Data |"<<endl;
cout<<"+---------------------------------------+"<<endl;
cout<<"|1. Add Instagram ID     |"<<endl;
cout<<"|2. Look All Data            |"<<endl;
cout<<"|3. Look Previous Data       |"<<endl;
cout<<"|4. Look Next Data       |"<<endl;
cout<<"|5. Exit             |"<<endl;
cout<<"+---------------------------------------+"<<endl;
int choose,l;
cout<<"your choices (1/2/3/4/5): ";cin>>choose;
switch(choose)
{
    case 1:
        {
            cout<<"Input limit : ";cin>>l;

            for(int a=1;a<=l;a++)
            {
                ig *new= new ig;
                new->next=NULL;
                new->prev=NULL;
                cout<<"Entry Number : ";cin>>new->id;
                cout<<"Instagram ID : ";cin>>new->name;
                cout<<"===================="<<endl;

                if(head== NULL)
                {
                    head=new;
                    tail=new;
                }
                else
                {
                    new->prev=tail;
                    tail->next=new;
                    tail=new;
                }
            }
        }

    cout<<"your choices (1/2/3/4/5)";cin>>choose;
    case 2:
        {
            while(head!= NULL)
            {
                cout<<head->id<<endl;
                cout<<head->name<<endl;
                head=head->next;
            }
        }
    cout<<"your choices (1/2/3/4/5)";cin>>choose;
    case 3:
        {
            if(tail=NULL)
            {
            ig *show;
            show=head;
            while(show!= NULL)
                {
                    cout<<head->id<<endl;
                    cout<<head->name<<endl;
                    head=head->prev;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Data belum terisi"<<endl;
            }
        }
    cout<<"your choices (1/2/3/4/5)";cin>>choose;
    case 4:
        {
            ig *show;
            show=tail;
            while(show!= NULL)
            {
                cout<<tail->id<<endl;
                cout<<tail->name<<endl;
                tail=tail->next;
            }
        }
    cout<<"your choices (1/2/3/4/5)";cin>>choose;
    case 5:
        {
            return 0;
        }
}
}
```

I tried to learn the logic of statement and the solution many times, but still unsuccessful. So I need help here, thank you

Comment: You should get a good c++ book.  Pretty much any one you pick up will cover switches and loops.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `while` around the `switch`:

```
while (true) {
    int choose = askChoice();
    switch (choose)
    {
        case 1: AddInstagramID(); break;
        case 2: LookAllData(); break;
        case 3: LookPreviousData(); break;
        case 4: LookNextData(); break;
        case 5: return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Three of your cases won't be handled.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Typo fixed thanks to Amit Kumar.